# MS Excel 2016 to PostgreSQL connection on Mac OS X with open source tools

Tags: excel, macos, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS and I want to be able to connect this with MS Excel 2016 on a local machine running Mac OS X.

On Windows the necessary drivers are free and this is a relatively straightforward process to set up. For Mac OS X it seems less straightforward. [MS support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/odbc-drivers-that-are-compatible-with-excel-for-mac-9fa6bc7f-d19e-4f7f-9be4-92e85c77d712) cites two examples, both of which charge for the necessary software.

I can successfully build according to [this documentation](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/unix-compilation.html), but I am not sure how to proceed after this. It seems I need to do some further configuring which I can't figure out. I have [ODBC Manager](http://www.odbcmanager.net/) and there's clearly a place to name new data sources and point to drivers, but I'm lost at this point and could use an example with explanation.

My question is this: Does anyone know of a good resource for getting this set up correctly using only open source tools, or at least approximating it? I am looking for good documentation or a helpful blog post, or really anything that will point me in the right direction for how to get everything configured correctly. Even if the right direction is "it's worth paying money for this".

Thanks

Comment: Excel for Mac is so far behind Excel for Windows, it's not funny. You'd get much better traction if you install Parallels and run Windows on the Mac hardware, like many people do who want the hardware quality of Mac and the capabilities of Windows apps. Mac alone is just for decoration and graphics design, as far as I'm concerned. If you want to do real data work, use Windows.